Why does HMAC-SHA1-96 need to pad message to a multiple of 160 bits?

HMAC-SHA1-96 is performed in AH of IPSec, to have data authentication and integrity.
I don't understand why I need to pad message M to a multiple of 160 bit, which is the output length of SHA1. Why is this needed?

AH-HMAC-SHA1 does not add any padding to the message it authenticates; I believe the text you are quoting is in error.
One possibility: perhaps the author you are citing misunderstood section 3.3.3.2.2 of RFC 2402 (which defines AH) - that section does talk about adding padding if the underlying crypto requires it.  That understanding would be correct if SHA-1 had a 'blocksize' of 20 bytes.  However, it does not - that section goes on to specifically say that SHA-1 is considered to have a block size of 1 byte (that is, padding is never required).

"SHA-1 is considered to have a block size of 1 byte".... but actually SHA-1 has 512 bit of block size... or are you referring to something different?

@allexj: I'm quoting from RFC 2402: "Note that MD5 and SHA-1 are viewed as having a 1-byte blocksize because of their internal padding conventions." (section 3.3.3.2.2, last sentence); that is, as far as AH is concerned, it is treated as if the block size was one byte (even though, if we look into the SHA-1 internals, it doesn't work that way at all).

ok thanks. so basically the author is wrong and the message does not need any padding. I just give message M (without padding it) to HMAC-SHA1 algorithm, right?

@allexj: well, you do need to zero out the 'mutable' bytes of M (RFC 2402 will tell you which ones those are) - this is what the author presumably meant by 'normalizing' it.  But yes, he is wrong when he talks about padding.

The source quoted in the question contradicts the relevant RFC 2404, The Use of HMAC-SHA-1-96 within ESP and AH, which states there is no need to pad the input data:

HMAC-SHA-1-96 operates on 64-byte blocks of data. Padding requirements are specified in FIPS-180-1 and are part of the SHA-1 algorithm. If you build SHA-1 according to FIPS-180-1 you do not need to add any additional padding as far as HMAC-SHA-1-96 is concerned.

At no moment in the HMAC-SHA-1 process is there a padding to a multiple of 160 bit by adding 0x00 byte(s). In particular, SHA-1 internally pads the message to form 512-bit (64-byte) blocks, and no part of that involves appending 0x00 bytes to the message until it's a multiple of something.
If we want to align the quote to the RFC, we must remove the first two steps in the quote, and use $\mathrm{M}$ where the is $\mathrm{M'p}$. If we did as in the question's quote, we'd generally end up with the wrong MAC.
Note: RFC 2402 §3.3.3.2.2 does state that if it's used an algorithm that requires padding, then padding should be with 0x00. But the aforementioned provisions in RFC 2404 state that padding is not necessary for HMAC-SHA-1-96, except as specified by SHA-1. In it's context where messages are an integral number of bytes, RFC 2402 can state that as follows :

Note that MD5 and SHA-1 are viewed as having a 1-byte blocksize because of their internal padding conventions.

